# All of us, including "me" or "I"

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

Which is better in this case, "me" or "I"?

> All of us, including me, have made mistakes.
>
> All of us, including I, have made mistakes.

It seems that "I have made mistakes" makes more sense than "me have made mistakes." But on other hand, "including me" makes more sense than "including I."

While typing this out I thought of a better way to phrase it so that it doesn't sound odd, but I would still like to know which is correct:

> All of us have made mistakes, including me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All of us, including **me**, have made mistakes.

It is not *have* that determines the case of the first person pronoun here but *including*, which always takes *me*. Not to compare with 'I have made mistakes'; but ask 'including whom?' --> Objective case.

However, with *I*, we could say,

> All of us, **I included**, have made mistakes.

With *myself*, as with *me*,

> All of us, including **myself**, have made mistakes.

Comment: I would also be happy with _me included_.

Comment: Thanks, "including whom?" was especially helpful

Comment: @DanielHarbour & up voter to the comment: That is besides the point. The sentence is an example of using *I*.

Comment: Nice to be of help, @andrewtweber. Keep coming back to ELU. :)

Comment: No harm in covering all bases though, @Kris.  It is more to the point than mention of _myself_: _me_ was at least in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since "including" is a preposition, it must take an object (unless it works as a particle in a phrasal verb, something not the case here). "I" is in the nominative case whereas "me" is in the objective case. Thus, "including me" is correct. "Including I" is incorrect in the same way that "for you and I" is incorrect: "for" must take a pronoun in the objective case despite the compound object. Most of us know enough not to say "for I" but the compounding of pronouns sometimes leads to confusion. What is important is the pronoun case not the verb.

"We have all made mistakes, including you and I." is incorrect usage because the subject of the verb "have" is "we" not "you and I," which are the compound object of the preposition "including."

Answer (score 1):

"All of us, including me, have made mistakes" is correct for the reasons given by Kris.

However:
"All of us, I included, have made mistakes" is an error, the position of the pronoun is inversion for emphasis, but it remains the object of "included". The group included me. To use "I" would need the passive voice: "I am included".

"All of us, including myself, have made mistakes." is also technically an error. "Myself" is principally used as reflexive: e.g. "I hit myself".

"Including myself" might qualify through common usage. "I included" surely doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

"I" is correct, even for the rephrased sentence. The reason "I" sounds weird in some of these cases is because it has been misused by many over the years. Think of it like this:

> "You and I have made mistakes."
>
> "We have made mistakes, including you and I."

Edit: Both "I" and "me" are words we use when we are referring to ourselves. The difference is that "I" (nominative) is used when we are the subject. In other words we are doing the work. We are making the mistake. "Me" (accusative) is used when something or someone else is doing work on us. As in "He fooled all of us, including me."

Edit 2: Now that I've thought about it further, Kris' reasoning does seem sound to me also. The case of the pronoun is determined by "including" rather than "made". Please use my reasoning as a cautionary tale at most.

Comment: But 'He fooled all of us, including me.'

Comment: In "He fooled all of us, including me", "He" is doing the work not you.

Comment: Yes – people have a tendency to see one correct example and use it in wrong contexts. This is merely an attempt to eliminate that possibility here.

Comment: I have added more explanation to my answer which may clear this up.

Comment: Can you supply some modern precedents for _including I_?  I looked through google books and didn't find any.  The phrase sounds hypercorrected to me and I think a native speaker's proper reaction on hearing it would be to guffaw.  I agree with Kris’ answer that _including_ must be followed by the accusative (which is the default form of the pronoun in contemporary English — _Me_ is the answer to _Who's coming?_, ousting erstwhile _I_), irrespective of the case of the argument to which it is an adjunct.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it further, Kris' reasoning does seem sound to me also. The case of the pronoun is determined by "including" rather than "made". "I" would be better suited to something like "We have made mistakes, both you and I." Although I would argue the answer to Who's coming? is I am.